# jQuery parsing string from server

Tags: php, jquery, tags

I'm getting a file from my server with the file_get_contents command. On the fly, when I use the inspect element of chrome, I can see the content of the file, which I assign in a jQuery string a few lines below. When I try to alert the variable I see nothing, in chrome's debugging  I see the error 
 **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**
The file has an xml format like this,

```
<test1> <test1.1>blabla </test1.1> </test1>
```

I tried to remove the bracket < and replace it with "& l t ;" but nothing happened

```
$file = './xxx/xxx/test.xml';
if (file_get_contents($file) != false) {
$str = file_get_contents($file);
}
```

jQuery

```
   $getvals = <?php echo $str ;?>;
   alert($getvals);
```

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: try with quotes   `$getvals = '<?php echo $str ;?>';`

Comment: thanks it worked, it didn't cross my mind that it may be that.